# How to get the `object` of the` ListChanged` event?

Tags: c#

To display data in `dataGridView`, I use`DataTable`, `BindingSource`.
I am adding a post.

**Question.**

How to get the fields of a new record in `Bs_ListChanged`?

```
namespace WinFormAppl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainMethod();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Метод логики
        /// </summary>
        public void MainMethod()
        {   
            bs.ListChanged += Bs_ListChanged;

            ConnectDataToDataGridView();
            AddColumnsDataTable();
            AddRowsDataTable();
        }

        private void Bs_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            //sender[i]. ????

        }

        #region Подготовка
        /// <summary>
        /// Connect data to DataGridView
        /// </summary>
        public void ConnectDataToDataGridView()
        {
            bs.DataSource = dataTable;
            dgv.DataSource = bs;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add columns
        /// </summary>
        public void AddColumnsDataTable()
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(string));            
        }


        ///// <summary>
        ///// Add rows
        ///// </summary>
        public void AddRowsDataTable()
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "str_1"});
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "str_2"});
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "str_3" });            
        }

        public void AddRowsDataTable_Test()
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "str_4" });

        }

        #endregion

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddRowsDataTable_Test();
        }
    }
```

---

### Update 1.

[image]

---

### Update 2.

```
 private void Bs_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded)
        {
            int i = e.NewIndex;
            BindingSource bs_1 = sender as BindingSource;

            DataRowView drv = bs_1[i] as DataRowView;                

            string s1 = drv.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            string s2 = drv.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: **[ListChangedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.8)**

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I do not understand. I want to get the "ID" and "Result" fields of a new record.
By the link you proposed, I don’t understand what properties of `ListChangedEventArgs` can solve my problem.

Comment: Everything you should need is in the `ListChangedEventArgs` argument. Set a breakpoint in your handler and look at the fields.  PLAY with it.  BTW, sender is always the control that created the event.  You will have to cast it to get at the actual class instance.

Comment: As @SeñorCMasMas has commented, you need to inspect the properties of the `e` parameter to your event handler, in particular you need to inspect the [ListChangedType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.listchangedtype?view=netframework-4.8) property to see that it *is* an addition, then check the [NewIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.newindex?view=netframework-4.8) property for the index of the new object that was added, then grab that object, and then inspect it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen See `Update-2`.
Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: The gist of it, yes, does it work? **Is** `sender` a `BindingSource` for instance? **That** I cannot help you with, but you got the parts about how to grab the object right, the details about the list you're using I don't know anything about.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I do not understand your message well.
But I think you said that I did everything right.

Comment: Let me rephrase :) I don't know the details about "BindingSource" and whether "sender" is such a thing, but the rest was spot on.